# Does Ethernet work at the FLIT level?

Tags: ethernet

Does Ethernet work at the FLIT level? If yes, then how are the frames converted into flit and vice versa?

If not, then what's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet doesn't use FLITs. The physical layer variants use various block codes, most prominently 4b5b, 8b10b and 64b66b. None of those use FLIT logic.

Ethernet frame building starts on top of the physical layer in the MAC layer (OSI data link layer).

For details see

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer
- [IEEE 802.3](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68) (free after registration)

Answer (score 0):

FLITs and Ethernet frames operate at more or less the same level of the networking stack, but they are used in different contexts. FLITs are a concept, mostly used in interconnection within chips and between chips within a node, while Ethernet is an actual standard used to connect nodes. So there is no direct mapping between the two. Note that PCIe 6.0 uses a specific implementation of the FLIT concept.